# Analytics graphs on mod tools

Tags: bug, moderator-tools

When reviewing moderator analytics graphs I have noticed that some of the axes don't return expected data. The most important one is the total page views - which seems to cut off months ago.

So I can get post data up to yesterday, but total views and visits, as you can see from two anonymised examples below, I only get to Jan 2014 in one case, and late 2013 in the other.

Example 1
[image]

Example 2
[image]

The important piece here is not the graphs themselves, or the values, but the horizontal axis. I understand there was a change in the way google analytics reports statistics, but I would expect that to be reflected possibly in a step change at that point, rather than just a lack of data.

Comment: Uh, I don't think this is much of a violation, but aren't those analytics reports kinda mods-only?

Comment: WHich is why I sanitised, picked 2 of the 6 sites I moderate, and tried to make sure it wasn't giving anything away :-)

Comment: What's the date range you're using?

Comment: The range is from private beta to now - I have tried various ranges, but it always comes up with a truncated range for Total views and New Visits

Comment: On the sites where I'm a moderator, this only happens when looking at full site history.  (I tried your beta-to-now example and got similar results.)  If I look at the last 3 months, I see current data.